# MS Access print driver or PDF

Tags: vba, ms-access, pdf, printing

I recently upgraded to a new server / and new version of Access to 2010 (up from 2003 I believe) and now when I try to use VBA to export PDFs (from my Report objects), it says "This document was previously formatted for the printer PDF Creator, but that printer isn't available."

Do I need to reinstall PDFCreator, or is there some default driver I should be able to use, etc?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the [so]! Could you please try to read your question from viewpoint of another person who doesn't know your context? For example what are version numbers  `new version of Access to 10 (up from 03 I believe)`. Those version numbers don't look familiar. I recommend you shortly check [ask] and edit your question.

Comment: MS Access 2003 vs MS Access 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access 2010 supports the output of reports directly to PDF with no other software required. For example,

```vbs
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "rptClients", acFormatPDF, "C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\foo.pdf"
```

As for the "document preiously formatted" message, it will persist until you reinstall the printer driver or update the reports to be formatted for the Default Printer:

[image: PageSetup.png]

Comment: What about merging files? (pdf to pdf)? Does Access support that natively? That was also something I used to use PDFCreator for.